# Convert excel subsheet into individual CSV in Azure storage cloud using Powershell

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a powershell script which should do following things:

1. Take Excel file from Azure blob storage folder 'A' as input
2. Extract subsheets from Excel and converts into the individual CSV
3. Transfer those CSV to same blob storage in folder 'B'

I am able to do 1 and 2nd step but in 2nd step I am getting excel file object which i have to transfer to blob storage folder 'B'.This is where i am not able to proceed. As for copyinh file to Blob has 2 methods :

1. Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy - this cmdlets can copy only blob but as i said i have file object.(look below for better understanding)

   > $wb = $E.Workbooks.Open($sf)
   >
   > foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets)
   >   I meant,I have $ws which is a object of excel file.

2.Set-AzureStorageBlobContent - this cmdlet requires local system file path, it means this cmdlets only upload file to blob from local system directory.

Can anyone suggest me the correct method to tackle this situation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: by "subsheets" you actuallly mean "sheets" right ?

Comment: Can't you save the worksheet as a file on local computer and then upload that file using `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`? After the file is uploaded, you can delete that file.

Comment: Would it work when it's deployed on Azure and Azure Runbook

Comment: @Mauricio Gracia Gutierrez - Subsheets are multiple sheets inside a Excel sheet..